# linux-firmware-nonfree hangs my system, but I need it for 3D graphics

Tags: graphics, firmware

I'm on Debian Sid, fully up-to-date. I need `firmware-linux-nonfree` in order to get 3D graphics, but unfortunately, when I install it, my system hangs at boot at the point where it waits for /dev to be populated.

I'm using System V Init (Debian default).

Is there anything I can do about this?

Here's my graphics card information:

```
alex-debian ओम् ~:(14h4m|git@master)
590 ± lspci | grep VGA    
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
alex-debian ओम् ~:(14h4m|git@master)
591 ±
```