# How to install Nvidia drivers on Debian Jessie

Tags: xorg, nvidia

I have installed the Nvidia drivers according to the [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_7_.22Wheezy.22) but with no success. The system hung during boot. How can I install the drivers successfully on Debian Jessie?

My PC's specs: GPU: GeForce 7600GS, kernel: 3.10-3-amd64

Comment: related (although maybe not, since that's AMD): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84744/linux-firmware-nonfree-hangs-my-system-but-i-need-it-for-3d-graphics

Comment: For nvidia-driver (319.76-1) [non-free], it only supports GeForce 8xxx and higher. Might need to use legacy driver. See http://packages.debian.org/jessie/nvidia-driver

Answer (score 8):

The basic steps are:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms linux-headers \ 
                     nvidia-settings nvidia-xconfig 
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

The last step is running `nvidia-xconfig` to set everything up. That should sort it all out, including blackisting the `nouveau` driver if you were using it. You'll have to reboot for it to take effect (well, you don't *have* to but it is much simpler that way).

Comment: I'll try this but a quick question if you will: wouldn't `nvidia-xconfig` make a /etc/X11/xorg.conf while the new suggested method of debian (for wheezy, at least) seems to use /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf ?

Comment: I ran into a problem during `sudo m-a auto-install nvidia-kernel${VERSION}-source`: http://i.imgur.com/GoYIkqr.png Then it requires me to install _linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64_ but they are only [available](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64) for wheezy

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. I trust apt to maintain the kernel for me. I do think that I run jessie: see http://paste.debian.net/46210/ and http://paste.debian.net/46211/

Comment: @sterz that's very strange, did you change your sources recently? Have you run `apt-get update`? Jessie is [on the 3.10 kernel](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-headers-3&searchon=names&suite=testing&section=all) and so should you. Anyway, there should be no problem if you install wheezy's package as long as that is the kernel you are using. I am just afraid there is an underlying problem. Ping me in the [U&L chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) and I can try and help you figure it out.

Comment: It seems these packages are not available anymore for jessie. What is the alternative?

Comment: @zoechi please post a separate question explaining your situation.

Comment: These packages were removed.
This explains it http://hackedbellini.org/linux/downgrade-and-force-some-packages-on-debian-to-a-previous-version/