# Debian 8 Nvidia İnstalling with Bumbleebee doesnt active

Tags: nvidia

i added /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.tu-graz.ac.at/mirror/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.tu-graz.ac.at/mirror/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.tu-graz.ac.at/mirror/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.tu-graz.ac.at/mirror/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

**After**

```
apt-get update
apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus
usermod -a -G bumblebee myuser
```

After rebooting

```
root@pc:/home/pc# lspci  | grep -i VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev ff)
```

And when i set this code

```
nvidia-settings
```

[image]

```
root@pc:/home/pc# nvidia-xconfig
bash: nvidia-xconfig: komut yok
root@pc:/home/pc#
root@pc:/home/pc# ls /etc/X11/
app-defaults         X   Xreset.d    Xsession.options
default-display-manager  xinit   Xresources  xsm
fonts            xkb     Xsession    XvMCConfig
rgb.txt          Xreset  Xsession.d  Xwrapper.config
root@pc:/home/pc# 
root@pc:/home/pc# glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer, 
root@pc:/home/pc# 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768 0 0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   1366x768      60.03* 
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Try the answer posted by @terdon http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92246/153195

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to start the bumblebee daemon:

```
# systemctl start bumblebeed
```

This starts the daemon, but if you reboot the daemon will need to be started again.  To fix this also run:

```
# systemctl enable bumblebeed
```

That will tell systemd to always start the daemon on startup

Note: This will need to be done as `root`